# how do i start with fresh with a new file

Tags: c#, exception

I catch an exception in my code for a wrong file type. Then i would like to change my file and use the correct file. How do i close the execption to look fresh at the new file and process it.

below is my code. one is a main function. the second is a called function.

main function.

```
  //data file process button
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            panel1.Visible = false; // File paths (Admin Access))
            panel3.Visible = true; // File process status
            label6.Visible = true; // label - File process status
            panel4.Visible = false; // Admin authenticate

            InitializeFile();
            ParseListFileData();
            ListArrayFileData();
            CleanDesiredData();
            GetRRData();
            GetLecoData();
            //cleanup();

            textBox5.Text += "All RR & Leconum data processing from file - " + textfilename + " completed." + "\r\n";
            textBox5.Text += "Please click EXIT to close HORIBA program" + "\r\n";
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            //cleanup();
            textBox5.Text += "Bad File" + "\r\n";
            datafilepath = "";
            textBox5.Text += "Select correct file" + "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

The Called Function ParseListFileData();

```
public void ParseListFileData()
    {
        //Opens file and uses for processing
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
        System.IO.StreamReader(datafilepath);

        try
        {
            //while loop to read file till end of file
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                //split data in file into differend fields
                var Row = sr.ReadLine();
                var values = Row.Split(',');
                ColmnA.Add(values[0]);
                ColmnB.Add(values[1]);
                ColmnC.Add(values[2]);
                ColmnD.Add(values[3]);
                ColmnE.Add(values[4]);
                ColmnF.Add(values[5]);
                ColmnG.Add(values[6]);
                ColmnH.Add(values[7]);
                ColmnI.Add(values[8]);
                ColmnJ.Add(values[9]);
                ColmnK.Add(values[10]);
                ColmnL.Add(values[11]);
                ColmnM.Add(values[12]);
                ColmnN.Add(values[13]);
            }

            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
        {
          sr.Close();
          sr.Dispose();
          datafilepath = "";
          //cleanup();
          //print(e.Message.("Error encountered");
          textBox5.Text += "File type not correct or missing data in file "+ e + "\r\n";
         }
    }
```

As soon as i select a new good working file, the old exception seems closed, but the old file still remains in use and shows an exception at another function. Even though i i use dispose() to close the streamreader resources.

How can i start fresh with a new file.

Comment: What do you mean by closing the exception? You never open or close an exception. You may be referring to the file. Which would be closed when you call the sr.Close(). If the datafilepath is not valid, you will never handle the exception. You should move the stream decleration in the try block.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing twice, but change one variable, put the whole thing in a function and pass in the variable as a parameter. Then call the function. O/T, your comments on the code that references your controls are very nice to see, but you can do even better: in the form designer you can change the names of the controls themselves: `panel1` can be renamed to `filePathsPanel`, for example.

Comment: when i get an exception i print bad file type. I want the user to select the correct file type and try again. but when new correct file is used, the program still seems to be looking at the old file. so unless i close the program and start again i cannot use a new file and process it even after having caught the exception. Thats why i wanted to know how do i start fresh with a new file after having caught an exception

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly is the problem, is the file handle not closed.

I see a problem with your code: you try and catch, but only on a specific exception, say you get an ArgumentException, this will not be caught, instead you can use `try{}catch{}finaly{}`

```
    try
    {
       /blabla
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {

      datafilepath = "";
      //cleanup();
      //print(e.Message.("Error encountered");
      textBox5.Text += "File type not correct or missing data in file "+ e + "\r\n";
     }
     finaly 
     { //this codes always runs wether exception or not.
      sr.Close();
      sr.Dispose();
     }
```

alternative and easier solution is to use using (which closes disposables automatically when done):

```
using(var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(datafilepath);) {
    //try catch in here. even is something goes horribly wrong. StreamReader = fileHandle will be closed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the "using". Plz see comment above. I get one exception only. but when i use the correct file type and try to process again, i get an error shows the previous file data is still being used . how do i move across that.